# TypeScript compilation failure and Karma test execution?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, webpack

I'm currently using Karma + Jasmine to run the tests on my TypeScript-based project, and I want to 'break the tests' when TypeScript compilation fail in karma watch mode.

I'm using standard Karma configuration and compiling TS using webpack preprocessor (which compiles TS files). Everything works perfectly fine, except that **seeing all tests pass when a compilation error occurs is highly misleading** (karma rerun previous tests even if webpack compilation fails).

It seems rather trivial, but after an hour or two of looking at documentation and searching Google I'm desperately looking for a solution, which I didn't find.

Is there a solution involving karma, jasmine, webpack and TypeScript that can break the tests when a compilation error occurs without breaking the watch mode?

edit : Precision on the watch mode added.

Comment: it's hard to say anything specific without seeing config files and best would be to see some very simple isolated project

Comment: In fact, the question is not "is my configuration ok or not" but rather "Is it possible ? And if yes, how did you do it on your project with a similar stack ?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

personally I am not using karma along with webpack in a single workflow. But remember from doing some research on using them together including typescript and there are issues https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack/issues/49 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/708 wihich you might be facing. So as mentioned `bail` option is not working as expected you can try using a plugin mentioned which will fail on TS error (quoting suggestion from [this comment to issue #708](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/708#issuecomment-70869174)).

**UPDATE:** As for the `watch` case I would consider a change that prevents webpack from failing but at the same time raising the error and prevent karma from executing tests as well (based on this [suggestion](https://gist.github.com/Stuk/6b574049435df532e905)).

```
module.exports = function (config) {

  config.set({

    browsers: [ 'Chrome' ],
    frameworks: [ 'mocha' ],
    reporters: [ 'mocha' ],

    files: [
      // ...
    ],

    // ...
    webpack: {
      plugins: [
          function()
          {
              this.plugin("done", function(stats)
              {
                  // Log each of the errors
                  stats.compilation.errors.forEach(function (error) {
                      console.log(error.message || error);
                  });

                  // Pretend no assets were generated. This prevents the tests
                  // from running making it clear that there were errors.
                  stats.stats = [{
                      toJson: function () {
                          return this;
                      },
                      assets: []
                  }];                      
              });
          }
      ]
    }
  })

}
```

I've just checked adding above plugin to fairly simple project https://github.com/itajaja/tslib-webpack-starter and tests are failing for any TS compilation errors.

Comment: At first, that looked quite good, but then I saw that the watch mode was not 'cleanly' supported... compilation error slain it when an error occurs.

Comment: and what behaviour would you expect in watch mode? the usual way I know is that all the workflow (ie compilation and tests) need to pass to start the watch mode. Then in case of failure it should properly recheck in case of any new change.

Comment: That's it ! Top notch ! The code you just posted works perfectly : no tests are run when a compilation error occur, and the error is logged in the console.
I just had to wrap the "stats.stats = [{...}]" with a "if (stats.compilation.errors.length > 0) {"...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This also works for me on Webpack 2.1.0-beta.25.

For what it's worth I also did what @M'λ' suggested in order to run tests if there are not errors and only warnings, since without it watch mode will also stop if there are warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with `tslint` warnings. All I was getting is `Compilation failed due to tslint errors`. Adding this setting in `webpack.config.js` took care of it:

```
bail: true,
```

This goes together with all the regular `webpack.config.js` settings. E.g.:

```
{
    context: __dirname + "/app",
    entry: "./entry",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    bail: true
}
```

Now I at least see the first tslint error before it fails.